# REST API Client only in HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, api, rest, client, csrf

Is it possible to create a client only in HTML / JS for a REST API and prevent CSRF?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

CSRF prevention is usually made for simple websites, not APIs, since APIs are generally intended to be accessed by other websites. Hidden crumbs and tokens, which are the most common way to prevent this kind of attack, won't work properly on consumable APIs.

What you probably need is a good main authentication mechanism. One of the main weaknesses of web applications vulnerable to CSRF are cookies. If your API doesn't need them, using another auth mechanism (like OAuth or HTTP Digest) may be the answer, so external users can still use the API safely (without nasty crumb verifications).

Both HTTP Auth Basic and OAuth 2.0 are feasible under JS client applications. There is a demo for OAuth2 here: https://gist.github.com/563893

Twitter uses its own public API inside the main website, so there is proof that something like this is possible, although I'm not sure how specifically they prevent external CSRF. Every request is made by a receiver (located here: https://api.twitter.com/receiver.html) and authorization tokens are tunneled by cookies. You'll probably need to research their implementation further.

Comment: How I can store the secret key on the client? (My client is a browser)